# Python: Beautiful Soup list is empy

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

When I print out the g_data list it is empty. There should be some information inside of it what am I doing wrong?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=coffee&geo_location_terms=Los+Angeles%2C+CA'
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "info"})

for item in g_data:
    print item.text
```

Comment: Unable to replicate. I copy/pasted this code got a list of items

Comment: are you sure there is a div with class info on that page? I inspected the content of the URL and didn't find any of these

Comment: There is and I am following this video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xQTJi2tqgk it works for him to. Could it be that I am using Python 2.7?

Comment: it runs fine on python 2, what do you get when you `print r.content`?

Comment: when I print r.content I get the html structure of the page. It's when I do soup.find_all("div", {"class": "info"}) that it does not work. But if I do soup.find_all('a') that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact same code works for me on Ubuntu`14 and Python2.7

You may try changing the parser to html5lib

```
pip install html5lib
```

and then,

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html5lib')
```

Comment: Thank you. Using this I got it to work.